# Prevent events while iTextBox has been edited in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, text-editor

I develop a program using `fabric.js`, with some `canvas` and `textEdit`.

The problem is I have a keyboard event listener, and when I type a letter in an `iTextBox`, if it coincides with a letter treated in the listener, it will also trigger the event.

Any thoughts on how to prevent this?

Edit:
Add a piece of the code what I'm using.

```
$( "body" ).keydown(function(e) {
    keyboardEvents(e);
});

function keyboardEvents(e){
    //Necesario para todo lo que no sea Chrome
    keyCode = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    //Pulsar "a" para crear una curva con linea nueva.
    if(keyCode == 65){
        /* Random Function*/
    }
}

function createNewTextBoxWithIndex(index){
    textBox[closedCurvesIndex-1] = new fabric.IText("Patrón "+index, {
        top: closedCurves[index-1][3]+30,
        left: closedCurves[index-1][2],
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        fill: '#000000',
        fontSize: 18,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        transparentCorners: false,
        cornerSize: 7,
        value: index  
    });

    canvas[0].add(textBox[index-1]);
}

createNewTextBoxWithIndex(1);
```

Comment: We're glad to help, but you'll need to post some code for us to review what you've tried.

Comment: which version of fabricks are you using? now the input has moved on the onInput event, no more on keypress. Maybe it already helps. what keys are you capturing in the keyboard event listener?

Comment: I edit the original post to add a few lines of the code. Soon I add a functinal feedl

Comment: I use fabric 1.4.0 by the way

Comment: Update to latest, iText works so better.

Comment: Updated question with tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually check the origin of the event and then design it . I dont have iTextBox but guess below approach will be similar.

In this snippet I have created two `input type =text` but I am listening to keyboard event only if it's origin is not from second input

HTML

```
<input type ="text" id="firstIp">
<input type ="text" id = "secondIp">
```

JS

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(event){
 var getEvtTarget = event.target.id;
 if(getEvtTarget !== "firstIp"){
   keyboardEvents(event)
 }

})
function keyboardEvents(event){
alert(event.keyCode)

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/noreLLxy/)

you can also check if the event is arising from iTextBox and if that is true then dont call `keyboardEvents` function.

Hope this will be helpful